# Pod install Realm 3.1.1 failed

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I used pod install Realm, some error appeared, after i searched by google, still can not found how to fix this error, please help me figure out how to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: As the person that added that check to Realm, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959181/1991710 is correct. Realm requires that the currently selected command line tools, as returned by `xcode-select`, point to a version of Xcode. Use `sudo xcode-select -s` as they suggest to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please re-check you have selected correct, latest version of xcode in Command line tools.

> XCode -> Preference -> Locations -> Command Line Tools

[image]

Change `xcode-select` developer directory to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Run

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

> NB: `Xcode.app` -> Your XCode app name

Comment: after i do this, the new issue coming:

Installing Realm (3.1.1)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: sync 2.2.9
Downloading sync failed:
 https://static.realm.io/downloads/sync/realm-sync-cocoa-2.2.9.tar.xz
 curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54


[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.2` on target `Realm` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Comment: could you please clean the product.(`Menu > Product > Clean`). & try again

Comment: re-install what? XCode or pod?